# How to use Math.LN(x) in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, math

How to use `Math.LN(x)` in ActionScript 3?

I have a formula to convert:

```
17.867 * LN(x)-29.263
```

How to write in ActionScript 3? I'm confused about how to write it.

What I've tried :

```
var Kc:Number;
var value_x:Number;

function enterFrameHandler () : void
{   
    value_x=80;
    Kc=(17.867)*Math.LN10(value_x) - 29.263;
    value_Kc.text=String(Kc);
    trace(Kc);
    //y = 17.867ln(x) - 29.263//

}

enterFrameHandler();
```

Getting error :

> Error : Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 7, Column 19 1195 : 
>   Attempted access of inaccessible method **LN10** through a reference with 
>   static type **Class**.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#log()

Comment: thanks for your help.. but i still not understand, thats why i need another explanation and any examples.. thank you..

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand. You cannot type **Math.log(x)** for whatever reason?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is the expected result vs your code result? Try something (show the code) and we can help you fix it to be more correct.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `Math.LN10(value_x)`?  Either you want `(Math.LN10 * Math.log(value_x) )` or you want `Math.log(value_x)`. Have you tested the algorithm you're converting? If yes, what answer for a random number like 5 (as `LN(5)`)? Tell us so we can advise how to get same result in AS3?

Comment: You cannot use Math.LN10 as a function.
LN10 is a Math constant for the natural logarithm of 10, expressed as loge10, with an approximate value of 2.302585092994046

trace(Math.LN10);    // output : 2.302585092994046

See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#LN10

Comment: @VC.One I think i want Math.log(value_x), yes i have tested LN(5)=1.609437912, actually this formula i got from equation curve in excel... thanks..

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your replied @Organis  may be directly show  problem in my code

```
var Kc:Number;
var value_x:Number;

function enterFrameHandler () : void
{   
    value_x=80;
    Kc=(17.867)*Math.LN10(value_x) - 29.263;
    value_Kc.text=String(Kc);
    trace(Kc);
    //y = 17.867ln(x) - 29.263//

}

enterFrameHandler();
```

///get error Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 7, Column 19   1195: Attempted access of inaccessible method LN10 through a reference with static type Class.//

Comment: Hi, you should [**edit your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44364563/edit) to add new details. Don't post as answer if not solution.

Comment: thanks your advice.. i'm sorry because i am still newbie and my english not good.. thanks..